# Javascript split number and string and keep both

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string

```
var houseNumber = '13a';
```

I want to split the addition from the number so I can keep it in a other field. 
How can I split this value without losing the number or the addition? At the end I would like to have 2 fields with the following type:

```
var houseNumber = 13; //Number
var addition = 'a'; //String
```

There are many questions about this, but I can't find one where both values has to be saved. That's why I created a new question.

Comment: Hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 2):

Use  the following code

```
var string_a = "jkjkhj89898";
var x = string_a.match(/[^\d]+|\d+/g);
console.log(x)
```

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajays871/uL19e5jx/).

Thanks

Comment: Please you should not answer a question that is duplicate. Soon you will earn privilege to close a question. Once you have it, please choose to close instead of answering a duplicate.

Comment: sorry i refreshed the page later, then it was marked duplicate.

Comment: When you see a basic question, there is a high possibility that this has been answered before. So you should search for these questions and if found, mark it as dupe or add a comment `Possible Duplicate <link>` so someone else can do it. Also there is no need for *sorry*. We all learn gradually. :-)